# GlobalEnergyGIS in julia - predictdemand() (SWE not found)

Tags: julia, gis

I followed the documentation steps butstill encountrer the following problem when using predictdemand(). Following terminal output:

```
`predictdemand(gisregion="Europe13", sspscenario="ssp2-26", sspyear=2050, era_year=2018)

Building training data for Europe13...

Reading auxiliary datasets...
Get current national electricity demand from IEA statistics...
Lookup SSP R5.2 region names for each GADM level 0 region...
Calculate demand multipliers...
Calculating annual electricity demand for model regions...
Progress: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| Time: 0:00:08

Reading temperature data for Europe13...

Reading auxiliary datasets...
Reading ERA5 temperature dataset...
0.476785 seconds (203 allocations: 1.499 GiB, 38.53% gc time)
Calculating population centers at ERA5 resolution...
ERROR: No population centers found for region SWE.
Stacktrace:
[1] error(s::String)
@ Base .\error.jl:33
[2] GIStemp(gisregion::String, scenarioyear::String, era_year::Int64, numcenters::Int64, mindist::Float64)
@ GlobalEnergyGIS C:\Users\luka.pirskawetz.julia\packages\GlobalEnergyGIS\rQD8B\src\GIStemp.jl:24
[3] buildtrainingdata(; gisregion::String, sspscenario::String, sspyear::Int64, era_year::Int64, numcenters::Int64, mindist::Float64)
@ GlobalEnergyGIS C:\Users\luka.pirskawetz.julia\packages\GlobalEnergyGIS\rQD8B\src\syntheticdemand_inputdata.jl:150
[4] predictdemand(; variables::Vector{Symbol}, gisregion::String, sspscenario::String, sspyear::Int64, era_year::Int64, numcenters::Int64, mindist::Float64, nrounds::Int64, max_depth::Int64, eta::Float64, subsample::Float64, metrics::Vector{String}, more_xgoptions::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
@ GlobalEnergyGIS C:\Users\luka.pirskawetz.julia\packages\GlobalEnergyGIS\rQD8B\src\syntheticdemand_training.jl:11
[5] top-level scope
@ REPL[30]:1`
```